# BadRequest while creating Leads in Salesforce using Rest Api

Tags: leads

When I am trying to create a lead in Salesforce using Rest API call, i am getting the response code as BadRequest.

Below are the details:

Url

```
https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Lead
```

BODY Json:

```
{
   "body": {
   "Salutation": "Mr.",
   "FirstName": "First Name",
   "LastName": "Last Name",
   "Company": "Company Name"
   }
}
```

Header:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Content-Type: application/json

Sforce-Auto-Assign: FALSE
```

Please let me know what is that i am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is wrong it should be like below for `/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Lead`:

```
{
   "Salutation": "Mr.",
   "FirstName": "First Name",
   "LastName": "Last Name",
   "Company": "Company Name"
}
```

Comment: Addition to this, I realized that the json string that i was sending was not formed correctly. My bad. Thanks for your answer.